# Auto hiding windows after clicking in background

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a lot of small windows on my site and my script close them when user clicks on the background

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#"+active);

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('#'+active).fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

The problem is they also hide when the user scrolls the site - how can I detect that the user is not just clicking the scroll bar?

Comment: i just need to add preventing from hidding when user scrolls page

Comment: Please clarify your question - you do NOT want the objects to hide if they are NOT in the viewport? then use `var $container = $('#'+active+':visible')` - and reuse the var: `$container.fadeOut(200);`

Comment: Or do you mean, when the user clicks the scroll bar, they are hiding too?

Comment: i do not want to hide objects if they are not in viewport. I want to not hide them when user clicks on scrollbar and scroll page with it.

Comment: try `if (e.clientX < $(window).width()-10)`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the event specifically on body instead of only on document:

```
$(document.body).mouseup ...
```